# How can I Debug an access violation with VS2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, access-violation

My C# application crashes for "access violation" on windows module. I tried to run it by Visual Studio debugger, but there I could not get any log or dump.
How can I use Visual Studio for debugging this kind of problem?

Comment: @ Tobia,Do you mean that it has this error during you double click the .exe directly in your project output folder? If so, please close all third party tools/processes in your windows, and make sure that you could run your app using the VS IDE. Or you could use the JIT debugging to get some information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac8kbaeh.aspx

Comment: I'm debugging my application developed with VS, it has an external dll refecence (I guess here there is the problem) and I would like to get the faulty method but when it crashes I cannot get anything from the VS debugger.

Comment: If you run your VS as the admin, and then debug it again, how about the result? If it is the reference of a project, please set the property "copy local=true", and then debug your app with step Into, please also make sure that the assembly was loaded in your debug mode window for this dll.

Comment: Did you find any solution?